# Easy way to do multiple nests in Pydantics Json output? (With FastAPI)

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

My basic data model looks like this:

```
class ArticleBase(BaseModel):
    headline: str
    text: str
    author_id: int

class Article(ArticleBase):
    id: int
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Now when using fastapi this gives me a json response of

```
{
'id': 1, 
'headline': 'a headline', 
'text': 'a text', 
'author_id': 1
}
```

But how would i get a response of the form:

```
{'data': 
    {'article': 
        {
        'id': 1, 
        'headline': 'a headline', 
        'text': 'a text', 
        'author_id': 1
        }
    }
}
```

One option would be to just create a

```
class ArticleArticle(BaseModel):
    article: Article
```

and then a

```
class ArticleData(BaseModel):
    data: ArticleArticle
```

but is that really the way to go? It seems like an endless amount of code.

Comment: As far as I know, that's what you would have to do. The Pydantic/FastAPI docs do seem to always have these different 'levels' of models.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom [json serializer](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation)

E.g.:

```py
import json


def custom_json(v, *, default):
    return json.dumps({"data": v}, indent=2, default=default)

class ArticleBase(BaseModel):
    headline: str
    text: str
    author_id: int

class Article(ArticleBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        json_dumps = custom_json


article = Article(id=1, headline="a headline", text="a text", author_id=1)

print(article.json())
```

Results in:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "headline": "a headline",
    "text": "a text",
    "author_id": 1,
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

I'm not sure on which logic you end up with the `article` section. So I left this for you to adopt my example :)